# Why is が used here?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-が, は-and-が

I still have trouble with the は and が particles.

> ほどなくして神様達はこの下界に住み付いた。多くの神様達**が**永住することを決めたらしい。

Why does が have to be used here?

What difference would it make if it were replaced with は instead?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but if you say 多くの神様達は永住することを決めたらしい in the second sentence, the relationship between 神様達 in the first sentence and and that of the second one becomes a bit unclear. "Soon, gods settled in this world (earth?)."  "Looks like many gods (who settled) decided to live here for long."

Comment: This isn't much help, but I vaguely remember 多くのxxx and 大勢のxxx coming up as special problematic cases in は/が analysis.

Comment: Is it still a problem for you when it's "…神様達は…住みついた。多くが永住することを…"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2番目の文で「が」を使ったことには、いくつかの理由があると思います。

一部、想像ですが、

- 作者が、「は」を繰り返すより、2番目を「が」にした方が美しいと感じたから
- 「が」の場合は、「自らの意思で」などの(積極的に何かをしたという)意味を含むから
- あまり意識せずに使った
- 2番目で「は」を使うと、「それ以外の神様は、別のことをした」という意味が生まれるから

「は」は、水彩画の薄い絵の具で塗り分けるようなイメージ、
「が」は、ボールペンのような、はっきりとした線で境界を描くイメージがあります。

「は」は、「○○のうち、△△は　□□した。(それ以外は xxした。)」というように、「一部が」というニュアンスを強調することになります。

---

With 「が」: "Many gods decided to live"

With 「は」: "Many gods decided to live, but others ..."